# get edit text value from view

Tags: java, android

I want to get the editext value and bitmap image from the every view that has bean created dynamically.I am not getting how to use it.I have tried to get the details from view vx.But it's not happening.Here is my code.

Please help...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText textIn;
Button buttonAdd;
LinearLayout container;
View addView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ArrayList<String> value=new ArrayList<String>();
    textIn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textin);
    buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
   Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.all);
    container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for (int i = 0, c = container.getChildCount(); i < c; i++) {

                View vx = container.getChildAt(i);

            }
        }
    });

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
                    (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            EditText textOut = (EditText)addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);
            textOut.setText(textIn.getText().toString());
            textOut.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {



                }
            });
            final ImageView buttonimg = (ImageView)addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            buttonimg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //((LinearLayout)addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                    buttonimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
                }});

            container.addView(addView);
        }});


}
```

}

Comment: `((EditText)vx.findViewById(R.id.textout)).getText()`?

Comment: yes you are absolutely right.Can you help how to get bitmap from imageview?

Comment: can you click on the answer and post your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @lenix Please post your comment as an answer and provide a brief explanation of why it works so that the OP can accept.

Comment: `((ImageView)vx.findViewById(R.id.remove)).getDrawable()`, if you need something other than Drawable then read the documentation of ImageView. If you really wrote the code above then this should be trivial for you. Good luck

Comment: I wanted the bitmap,not the drawable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For retrieving the text:

```
((EditText)vx.findViewById(R.id.textout)).getText()
```

Comment: Make sure to add "toString()" to the end in order to get a String value.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the answer since I haven't got the answer about how to get the imagebitmap. This code is working

```
         ImageView v2=((ImageView) vx.findViewById(R.id.remove));
         Bitmap bm=((BitmapDrawable)v2.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Good luck